# How to cast an Object to an Object Array

Tags: .net, vb.net

What is the proper syntax for casting an object to an Object(). Here's an example:

```
Dim obj as Object = {1,2,3}   'integer array or array of anything
Dim objArr as Object() = CType(obj, Object())
```

I can't seem to find the correct way to do this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no syntax for that, as it's not possible. You can't cast an integer array to an object array, because an integer is not an object.

Casting the object reference to an integer array reference works fine:

```
Dim objArr As Integer() = CType(obj, Integer())
```

You can cast each integer in the array to an object to create an object array with the values from the integer array:

```
Dim objArr As Object() = CType(obj, Integer()).Cast(Of Object)().ToArray()
```

#### Edit:

As you edited your question to include any type of array, not just an integer array, casting to `IEnumerable` as you suggested works fine as any type can still be cast to Object in the next step:

```
Dim objArr As Object() = CType(obj, IEnumerable).Cast(Of Object)().ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this without using LINQ? Maybe somehow with Array.ConvertAll(); but better than foreach ... copy to the new array.

Comment: @Gaffa, corrected your answer to use IEnumerable because in my original problem I didn't know that obj was an array of integers, it could be an array of anything. Changing the type to IEnumerable seems to cover all cases...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't just cast an array of Integer to an array of Object.

You can cast to an array:

```
Dim objArr As Array = CType(obj, Array)
Dim objArr2 As Object() = objArr.OfType(Of Object)().ToArray()
```

Or you can use Array.ConvertAll:

```
Dim objArr As Object() = Array.ConvertAll(Of Integer, Object)(obj, Function(t) t)
```

Or you can cast to an array of Integer, which is what it really is:

```
Dim objArr as Integer() = CType(obj, Integer())
```

Comment: Suppose I don't know that the array is Of Integer. Suppose all I know is that it is an array of something. Is there a way to rewrite the ConvertAll? I tried doing Array.ConvertAll(Of Object, Object)(obj, Function(t) t) but that doesn't work.

Comment: I think something like `Dim objArray As Object() = CType(obj, Array).OfType(Of Object)().ToArray()` might work.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing a part of the context but from your example, the problem isn't the cast itself but the way you create your object.

Instead of creating an object, you should create an object array.

```
Dim obj As Object() = {1, 2, 3}   'integer array
Dim objArr As Object() = obj
```

However, if you can't apply this in your context, then [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23480897/315493) is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, this is old legacy code and yes, I agree with you that the object should be created correctly but it wasn't in a lot of places.